# What's the best practice when defining dimensions in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When writing Compose UI, one way is to directly use `dp` value for example, `20.dp`, or defining the value in `dimensions.xml` then use `dimensionResource` in the code to get the value.

I try to find the best practice in the official doc but unfortunately I could not find any related information so I'm wondering which way should be used.

Comment: Please make a file `Dimen.kt` and declare the dp's there

Answer (score 1):

It depends on if you want to vary the dimensions based on device configuration, and if your app has a mix of view-based and Compose.

If the application is Compose-only and dimensions you're defining are consistent across any device configuration, you can just use a common constant or explicit literals everywhere. For example, if you're defining margins that will be the same everywhere, this would be a reasonable approach. You can define constants in an `object` for scoping:

```kotlin
object Dimensions {
    val margin = 8.dp
    val icon = 48.dp
}

Modifier.padding(Dimensions.margin)
```

or

```kotlin
object Dimensions {
    const val margin = 8
    const val icon = 48
}

Modifier.padding(Dimensions.margin.dp)
```

If, however, you want to share dimensions with views, or want to vary based on device configuration, such as using different values for portrait vs landscape, different versions of Android, different locales, etc. (See [Provide alternative resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources)) you'll want to use a resource file like `dimensions.xml` with alternative definitions in other resource dirs (such as `values-sw720dp`)